# Is it correct to receive a JSON as a string?

Tags: java, json

Is it correct if I use a String parameter to accept a JSON like that:

```
@POST 
@Path("/test") 
@Produces("application/json") 
@Consumes("application/json")
public Response test(String jsonObject) {
//someStuff, get value of key 

return outputAsJson
}
```

jsonObject = {"key":"value"}

outputAsJson = {"key2":"value2"}

So I have got another way to display a JSON: create a class with the parameters of the expecting JSON input.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.You can use string parameter to accept a JSON string in you Resource class.Then you have to parse it to get individual key/value .

But better way is "the another" way you have mentioned. Write a class and use @BeanParam to set the expected JSON input.

Comment: Thank you! So I  will go with my class solution later.